# Don't track tag badges for synonymized tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-badges, badge-progress

It's not a big deal, but if we want a feature to automatically track the next tag badge maybe we also want it to be functional.

It's not too bothering if you have a tag stuck to a score low enough for the next tag badge for that tag, but I was lucky enough to have the tag [shell-scripting](/questions/tagged/shell-scripting) synonymized when I had a score of 94 on that tag:

[image: s1]

[image: s2]

I.e. that broke the automatc tracking feature for me, because I won't see another tag badge automatically tracked until I'll have more than 94% of the required score for that tag badge (unless of course I pick one manually, but that misses the point of automatic tracking).

Worst case scenario would be having the tag synonmized at a score of 99 / 399 / 999, which would make the automatic next tag badge tracking feature completely pointless.

(by the way who needs to track a synonymized tag?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *correct* solution to this is to get the moderators on your site to either:

1. Conduct the merge so there are no longer questions tagged with the synonym. Once all the questions have been retagged by the merge, your tag score will transfer to the new tag when the recalc runs and the old synonym tag will no longer be eligible for tag badges (and thus won't appear in your tracking system anymore).
2. Remove the synonym if it is incorrect. If the synonym gets deleted, then everything continues on as normal and you can keep answering new questions in that tag to work towards your tag badge.

A synonym having questions tagged with it is meant to be an entirely temporary state while it's waiting for one of the two above actions to happen to it.

You do have the tag score in that tag, and that is your progress towards getting the tag badge. It actually makes sense to still display and suggest these, because **you can still earn the tag badge** by receiving upvotes on your answers which already have that tag or posting new answers to questions which already had it. It's just that no *new* questions can have that tag added while the synonym exists.

If you don't want to track that tag badge, which seems likely, you can always change which tag badge it's tracking by using the little gear icon to the left of it.

Comment: Fair enough, I missed the point that I can still earn score on that tag for old answers. I'll ask a mod to conduct the merge, although technically speaking that would leave a trackable "unscoreable" tag in the list (not that it would bother anyone, but still). Maybe still untrack synonymized and merged tags? In this case for example in my opinion the synonym should stay.

Comment: @kos Tags with under 100 questions aren't eligible for tag badges, so any merged synonym will not show up in the list. (Technically speaking, once the synonym is merged, the synonym "tag" doesn't even exist anymore.)

Comment: Ah, my bad, didn't know about that. Then it sounds perfect. Thanks!